# Allowance for cremation if no space in Jewish cemetery?

Tags: halacha, funeral-burial-levaya, fire-burning

Is it permissible to be cremated if one does not have space for burial in a cemetery?

Source, please.

Note: Not related to recent events (ie coronavirus).

Comment: Go in the backyard and dig a grave. There’s no obligation to be buried in a cemetery, just to be in the ground.

Comment: @DonielF -- That is not legal in most jurisdictions.

Comment: @Maurice OP doesn’t say anything about Dina d’malchusa in this question.

Comment: Just push the bones over and squeeze someone else in like they used to do in the kuchin.